# What's the advantage of using Zend Developer Solution over Zend Studio?

Tags: php, ide, zend-studio

Got a call today from sales and Zend and they were pushing the Zend Developer Solution (bundles Zend Studio and Zend Server). Since I'm with a start up the cost is an issue, and the developer solution is almost twice as much as just buying Zend Studio.

The sales person told me that with Zend Developer Solution you will be using and testing "Business Grade" PHP.

Can anyone tell me what this means? If you have experience with both, please let me know your thoughts on whether or not there's a big advantage for a relatively small dev team (9 developers)

Comment: marketing BS, just want to sell zend server which is inferior to Apache (the industry standard)

Comment: Thanks Dagon! That validates what I thought. I guess they really need money, so upsell and cross-sell are their standard techniques!

Comment: every one does it, we do :-( (well the marketing department)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. We use Zend Studio and MAMP and don't see the need for Zend Server.

Answer (score 0):

If cost is an issue why don't you go for eclipse PDT ?

It is the open source version of Zend Studio and it id a pretty decent PHP IDE